# Drag and Drop a Button in Android

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop, draggable

I need some tutorials on Drag and Drop a Button in Android. I mean, I have some buttons in a row and when I Long press any of the button than i can reposition the selected button in between my existing buttons and all other buttons moves aside.

Can anybody provide some nice tutorials or guides for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Call below listener in button:

```
myOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me){
             if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                 oldXvalue = me.getX();
                 oldYvalue = me.getY();

             }else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE  ){
                LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(),(int)(me.getRawX() - (v.getWidth() / 2)), (int)(me.getRawY() - (v.getHeight())));
                v.setLayoutParams(params);
             }
             return true;
         }
     };
```